# easy_install not working with no error

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, easy-install

I'm trying to get new packages (request for example) and trying to do it through easy_install, but when I try to open it (both easy_install and easy_install-3.6) all I get is a blank terminal screen popping up for a second and than closing with nothing happening. What's wrong with it and how can I get new packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`easy_install` must be used as a command in the command prompt and it cannot be opened as an application. Go to the folder where `easy_install` is and open command-prompt in that folder. Now perform installation of any libraries using:

`>easy_install pandas`      `#example`

Or you can set this path in your environment variables and use it instead of using this path to install everytime.